# Where is the working directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, mnist

I ran this code on my machine using Jupyter Notebook, thinking it may not work since the relative directory doesn't exist...However, it turns out it worked. So the relative directory used `/datasets/ud730/mnist` must be relative to current working dir which is `C:\\Users\\george.liu\\OneDrive\\WorkingDir\\Temp`. However, I was not able to find any related folders or files. I also checked `C:\\Users\\george.liu`, nothing there either...What am I missing? Where does the file go? Thanks!

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

n_input = 784  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# Import MNIST data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/datasets/ud730/mnist', one_hot=True)

# The features are already scaled and the data is shuffled
train_features = mnist.train.images
test_features = mnist.test.images

train_labels = mnist.train.labels.astype(np.float32)
test_labels = mnist.test.labels.astype(np.float32)

# Weights & bias
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_classes]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
```

EDIT:

I did check current working dir using this code:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

and this is the result:

'C:\Users\george.liu\OneDrive\WorkingDir\Temp'

Comment: how about C:\datasets\ud730 ...

Comment: Did you try searching for the file in your file manager?

Comment: why don't you print `os.getcwd()` while running? and I confirm that on windows `'/datasets/ud730/mnist'` can be seen as relative (not on linux obviously)

Comment: Thanks @Loïc! Yes, you're right. It's at C:\datasets\ud730. But isn't relative directory supposed to be relative to our current working dir?

Comment: @GeorgeLiu `/datasets/ud730/mnist` does not look relative to me. I don't have a windows box handy, though.

Comment: The leading slash means that this is an absolute path, not relative.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Prune!

Comment: actually it is _not_ ignored. It has a meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux `/datasets/` is an absolute path

But on Windows machine, if you have a subdirectory `python` in your current drive, ex `D:\python` and the current directory is *somewhere* in `D:` (not necessarily at root, could be: `D:\python` already) you can do `os.chdir("/python")` and it works like if you did `os.chdir(r"D:\python")`

So the slash is *not* ignored, it's just like `:\` (root of current drive)

In your case, python looks for `C:\datasets\ud730\mnist` since the current directory is somewhere on drive `C:`.

You can check that by printing `os.path.abspath('/datasets/ud730/mnist')`